# Can someone explain how image cropping works?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm new to image processing. I found the following cropping technique from Kaggle. Can someone explain how it is actually cropping the image?

```
def edge_and_cut(img):
    try:
        edges = cv2.Canny(img, img_w, img_h)            
        
        if(np.count_nonzero(edges)>edges.size/10000):           
            pts = np.argwhere(edges>0)
            y1,x1 = pts.min(axis=0)
            y2,x2 = pts.max(axis=0)
            
            new_img = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]           
            new_img = cv2.resize(new_img,(img_w, img_h))  
        else:
            new_img = cv2.resize(img,(img_w, img_h))
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        new_img = cv2.resize(img,(img_w, img_h))
    
    return new_img

def crop_images(Imgs):
    CroppedImages = np.ndarray(shape=(len(Imgs), img_w, img_h, 3), dtype=np.int)

    ind = 0
    for im in Imgs: 
        x = edge_and_cut(im)
        CroppedImages[ind] = x
        ind += 1

    return CroppedImages
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output Image]

Comment: please define what you mean by "how it is actually cropping the image". what part of the code don't you understand?

Comment: Not any particular part of code, but I have doubt in the complete process of cropping using canny edge detection. Like after cropping, what exactly is happening to identify the boundary box?

Comment: cropping is the last step here. nothing happens after.

Comment: Sorry, not after cropping, I mistakenly wrote cropping. I mean after finding edges , how those min and max functions work and how the bounding box is identified after the edge detection?

Comment: you could use a debugger and watch the variables while running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cv2.Canny](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d5c/tutorial_canny_detector.html) is *Canny Edge Detector*. If I understand correctly its output is treated as binary image (consisting of cells representing "edges" and "not-edges") and then it does find minimal bounding box (rectangle) which does hold all "edges" cells. This box is extracted from image.

Comment: This is not really answer the question, it is about how image cropping works, not about canny.

Answer (score 1):

The cropping part is done by:

```
    new_img = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```

Here you are slicing the image array from y1 to y2, and x1 to x2, so you are just keeping that area of the image, which is the rectange enclosed by points (x1,y1), (x1,y2), (x2,y1), (x2,y2). In this particular case the area is selected by cv2's Canny Edge Detector, as [mentioned by Daweo above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67498935/can-someone-explain-how-image-cropping-works/67499083#67499083).